# Use lua os.execute in windows to launch a program with out a flash of CMD

Tags: windows, lua, command-prompt

I am happily launching a program in a windows system from Lua using

```
strProgram = '"C:\\Program Files\\Ps Pad\\PSPad.exe"'
strCmd = 'start "" '..strProgram
os.execute(strCmd)
```

This works correctly, launching the program and the script finishing.
How ever it flashes up a command window for a fraction of a second,  does any one have a way from Lua to launch a program.

Comment: What happens if you just run `strProgram` instead of `strCmd`?  In other words, do you really need the `start`?

Comment: The Command window stays open all the time the launched program is running and the Lua script hangs until the program has been closed.

Comment: From the docs, it looks like they are running it through the OS shell (sorry, I'm on Linux so I couldn't test this myself).  Unless someone knows a Lua trick, you may need to write your own function in the host language (e.g. C) that does a `fork/exec` instead of the `system` call and export that API out to Lua.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lua's os.execute command is based on the C standard library "shell" function. In Windows, this function will always create a command window, and it will always halt your current process until the window finishes. The latter also happens in Linux.

There is ultimately no way around this. Not through the Lua standard API. Because Lua needs to be light-weight and platform independent, the API is not allowed to use OS-dependent native APIs.

Your best bet would be to use the [Lua Ex-Api](http://code.google.com/p/lua-ex-api/) module. It is effectively abandonware, and you may need to patch up a few compiler issues (I'm guessing the Windows port wasn't their first priority). But it is a reasonably good way to spawn processes. You can choose to wait until it finishes yourself, or let them run in parallel. And it won't throw up a command prompt window, unless the application itself uses one.

Comment: Thanks for that, I am afraid that looks a bit beyond my skill set, I will pass it on the person whose software has Lua in and see if he can add a function for me and I'll point him at that code if he needs it.

Comment: I believe there is at least one way to execute a command without the console popping up on windows with no extra library, using io.popen. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the piece of code I use to  call a batch from Lua, maybe help.
In win console (command prompt) open and execute, same  in unix (mac|nix)

```
-- sBatchFile = .bat for windows, .sh for x
function vfFork2(sBatchFile)
    local b = package.cpath:match("%p[\\|/]?%p(%a+)")
    if b == "dll" then 
        -- windows
        os.execute('start cmd /k call "'..sBatchFile..'"')
    elseif b == "dylib" then
        -- macos
        os.execute('chmod +x "'..sBatchFile..'"')
        os.execute('open -a Terminal.app "'..sBatchFile..'"')
    elseif b == "so" then
        -- Linux
        os.execute('chmod +x "'..sBatchFile..'"')
        os.execute('xterm -hold -e "'..sBatchFile..'" & ')
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to run a command without a console window using only the Lua standard API (i.e. no extra libraries). Tested on Win7 x64.

```
function exec_silent(command)
    local p = assert(io.popen(command))
    local result = p:read("*all")
    p:close()
    return result
end
```

Edit: see the comments below, it might not work for everyone. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Negative, Win7 64 bit and it behaves the same as with just popen or execute (Lua 5.2.3, linked)

Comment: @handle There is obviously something different about our setups then. I'm using this code almost every day in a build system and I have no command windows popping up at all.

Comment: not doubting you, just preparing others that this may not work despite your success.

Comment: @handle sure, I added a warning to my post as well.

Comment: Negative for me as well, Lua 5.1, Win11