# how to avoid popup a window when use os.execute in lua

Tags: windows, lua

I am using `os.execute()` to call other program in Lua, when program run,the cmd windows will popup for a blink, and I call the execute more than hundred times, and it become annoying.
So is there any way to set the window invisible?

Comment: Unless the command provides a quiet mode of execution, no. Many programs have optional argument of `-q` or `--quiet` or `-d` or `--daemon` to stay hidden.

Comment: If you have access to the LuaCom module, depending on  what you are trying to do you might be able to use a direct windows api (assuming you are running on windows.  Alternately check if your host application supports shellexecute. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362841/use-lua-os-execute-in-windows-to-launch-a-program-with-out-a-flash-of-cmd?rq=1

Comment: What command are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer was given by hjpotter in a comment: ***no, you can't***.

A longer explanation follows.

On Windows executable files come in "two flavors": **GUI applications** and **command line applications**. This has nothing to do with the inner workings of the program, but it depends on how the program was built (there is a flag for it in the PE executable header which can be set using a linker option). It is the OS that automatically pops up a console window (the "ugly black box") when a command line application is executed.

The problem with `os.execute` is that it [uses C `system` function under the hood](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/loslib.c.html#os_execute), which in turn is probably implemented by executing the Windows command shell executable `cmd.exe`, which **is** a command line application. Thus every time you use `os.execute` you are indeed executing `cmd.exe`. That black box is the console window associated with `cmd.exe` being executed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. `os.execute("sleep 5")` doesn't show a command line window. It's probably the program he is executing is creating its own window.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Are you using a Windows OS? AFAIK `sleep` is not a Windows default command (unless they added it in Windows 7, which I haven't got at hand now).

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Yes, I am using Windows 7. `sleep` from msys, but that's not the point. I can also do `os.execute('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua5.1/lua.exe"')` in a Lua shell running under cmd.exe and it will run in the same terminal window.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo What do you mean by "it's from msys"?. About your next sentence: if you execute a script from an already open command shell, it won't open another, so you won't see the effect experimented by the OP. Try to put `os.execute` in a script and double click on that script from the Windows GUI shell and see what happens.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo To be more specific, try to execute a GUI program using `os.execute`. For example: `os.execute("notepad.exe")`. And do this executing the Lua script by double clicking on it in the GUI shell.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Sorry, I meant `sleep` was from MSYS.
Just tried what you said both with `echo` and `notepad.exe`. They both only create the cmd.exe window for Lua; they don't create additional command windows.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Then I wasn't wrong. I never said `os.execute` creates *additional* `cmd.exe` windows. I said that you ***can't avoid creating one***.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37423/discussion-between-colonel-thirty-two-and-lorenzo-donati)

Answer (score 7):

I personally wasn't happy with the "No, you can't" answer and being the Engineer type of guy that just has to "SOLVE THAT PROBLEM", I was able to get things to work using WScript.Shell:

```
Shell = luacom.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell:Run (command, 0)
```

The "0" is used to suppress the popup from occurring.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. After some experimenting I found that to do a "shellexecute" without flashing a window you cannot do Shell:Run("start url", 0) but have to do a Shell:Run("cmd /C start url", 0). Maybe this is helpful for others looking here.

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional solution I imagined using the alien library.

[Alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/) is a library to access windows dll's with lua in a disciplined way. In order to execute a command file without opening a shell window the function `ShellExecuteA` from the `Shell32.dll` can be used: its documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a suitable approach is described by the following snippet.

```
require 'alien'
local shell32 = alien.load('Shell32.dll')
shell32.ShellExecuteA:types("pointer","pointer","pointer","pointer","pointer","pointer","int")
local exec = shell32.ShellExecuteA

function osexec(cmd, open)
  if open then
    -- execute opening a window
    exec(0,"open","cmd.exe","/C "..cmd,0,3)
  else
    -- execute, no window opened
    exec(0,"open","cmd.exe","/C "..cmd,0,0)
  end
end
```

Calling the previous function with the command only, runs it without opening a window, calling with two operands `osexec ("dir", true)` opens a window and is useful for debugging purposes.