# C# runs a lua script which calls cmd. How to hide the cmd window?

Tags: c#, cmd, lua

Lua:

```
function test()
    local t = io.popen("cd")
    for line in t:lines() do
        print(line)
    end
    t:close()
end
```

C#:

```
using LuaInterface;

public void Lua_Test()
{
    Lua lua = new Lua();
    lua.DoFile(@"lua\test.lua");

    var Lua_Test = lua.GetFunction("test");

    Lua_Test.Call();
}
```

When I run the lua in SciTE, cmd window will not show. But the cmd window will appear(and quickly closed) when the lua is called by C#. Is there any way to hide the cmd window or avoid it appearing?

By the way, I don't want to use the VBScript way to reopen the bat file.

Both io.popen and os.execute will create a cmd window, I want to solve both cases.

Edit:
Well, I know lua uses C system function so normally the cmd window will appear. But why the window won't show when lua running in SciTE? (Ok, I figured out, that is the SciTE has already opened a cmd window)

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365296/2417602). It might help.

Answer (score 0):

[Luacom WScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20505107/5464722)

Well, I decide to use the solution above, better than writing vbs in bat script in my case, which is my C# will call lua many times. Unlike vbs, this method will only create the shell once, and it can call Run method many times.